# Showing that $\sin(z+w)=\sin z\cos w+\cos z\sin w$, using the complex exponential definitions of sine and cosine

Tags: complex-numbers

Use the definitions
$$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2\qquad\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$
to show that
$$\sin(z+w)=\sin z\cos w+\cos z\sin w$$
I'm not quite sure on how to approach this question. My first attempt was substituting each of the terms on the right hand side with the definitions given i.e. letting $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ equal the definitions above, and then doing the same but substituting $w$ into the terms, but this didn't seem to lead me anywhere.

Comment: Any approach to simplify RHS after substituting for some and cosine?

Comment: Your "first attempt" is exactly the right thing to do. Maybe you just hit an algebraic snag. Show your work and we should be able to help you identify the error.

Comment: I ended up with one fraction with multiple e terms on the top, with the denominator being 4i. I'm not sure if I've done it correctly but I have 5 terms on the top; 2e^(iz+iw) and then four others with alternating signs, e.g e^iz-iw-e^iz+iw. Sorry if this is quite unclear, I'm not sure how to format this well

Comment: I have 2e^(iz+iw)+e^(iz-iw)-e^(iz+iw)-e^(-iz-iw)-e^(-iz+iw) denominator 4i

Comment: Just got it, made a stupid mistake, thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin z\cos w+\cos z\sin w=\dfrac{(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})(e^{iw}+e^{-iw})+(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})(e^{iw}-e^{-iw})}{4i}$$

$\dfrac{\text{The numerator}}2$
$$=e^{i(z+w)}-e^{-i(z+w)}+e^{i(z-w)}-e^{i(w-z)}-e^{i(z-w)}+e^{i(w-z)}$$

Comment: I just worked it out, thank you